# Virtuoso DBpedia "Other Language than English" graph

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, virtuoso, iri

I'm trying to use Virtuoso with ita-Dbpedia dumps.
These are the steps i've done using the guide:

1: Installed virtuoso and made a Service (called "Nostromo").
2: Downloaded Dumps
3: Bulkloaded dumps
4: registered graph iri with (SQL> ld_dir ('tmp', '*.*', 'http://dbpedia.org')
5: Inserted the graph file in the 
6: started the loader Run: SQL> rdf_loader_run (); (5 hours wait...)

Than all seems good but when i try to sparql something it results empty...

with the SQL command:

```
SELECT ll_graph, ll_file FROM DB.DBA.LOAD_LIST;
```

it comes:
Query result:

```
> ll_graph VARCHAR  ll_file VARCHAR  http://it.dbpedia. org 
> tmp/itwiki-20140302-article-categories.ttl  http:// it.dbpedia. org   
> tmp/itwiki-20140302-article-templates.ttl  http:// it.dbpedia. org    
> tmp/itwiki-20140302-available_interlanguage-links.ttl 
> http:// it.dbpedia. org    tmp/itwiki-20140302-category-labels.ttl 
> http:// it.dbpedia. org    tmp/itwiki-20140302-disambiguations.ttl 
> http:// it.dbpedia. org    tmp/itwiki-20140302-external-links.ttl 
> http:// it.dbpedia. org    tmp/itwiki-20140302-geo-coordinates.ttl 
> http:// it.dbpedia. org    tmp/itwiki-20140302-images.ttl 
> http:// it.dbpedia. org    tmp/itwiki-20140302-infobox-properties.ttl 
> http:// it.dbpedia. org   
> tmp/itwiki-20140302-infobox-property-definitions.ttl 
> http:// it.dbpedia. org    tmp/itwiki-20140302-infobox-test.ttl 
> http:// it.dbpedia. org    tmp/itwiki-20140302-instance-types.ttl 
> http:// it.dbpedia. org    tmp/itwiki-20140302-interlanguage-links.ttl 
> http:// it.dbpedia. org    tmp/itwiki-20140302-labels.ttl 
> http:// it.dbpedia. org   
> tmp/itwiki-20140302-mappingbased-properties.ttl  http://it.dbpedia.
> org    tmp/itwiki-20140302-page-ids.ttl  http://it.dbpedia. org   
> tmp/itwiki-20140302-page-links.ttl  http://it.dbpedia. org    
> tmp/itwiki-20140302-redirects.ttl  http://it.dbpedia. org 
> tmp/itwiki-20140302-revision-ids.ttl  http://it.dbpedia. org  
> tmp/itwiki-20140302-revision-uris.ttl
```

and with:

```
SELECT ?g COUNT(*) { GRAPH ?g {?s ?p ?o.} };
```

it comes:

```
g   callret-1
http://www.w3. org/2002/07/owl# 160
http://it.dbpedia. org  86712483
http://www.openlinksw. com/schemas/virtrdf# 2639
http://local.host:8890/sparql   14
http://local.host:8890/DAV/ 2939
```

pratically i know that there are the triples, but i can't query them...

PS: 
for example i use a query that works fine in another ita-sparql endpoint, but it's not good for mine...

```
SELECT ?museum, ?artwork WHERE {
?museum a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Museum>. 
?museum <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/address> ?address.
?artwork <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/location> ?museum.
 FILTER contains(?address, "Firenze")
}
```

I think it's a quite stupid mistake i've done, but i can't find it...

***UPDATE  07/01/2014***

With this query i got a result:

```
select ?museum where {
  graph <http://it.dbpedia.org> {
    ?museum a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Museum>. 

  }
}
```

But no news with the other query 
I think it's about ontology...

are there some query/interrogation i can do for help you understand this problem?
(Thanks in advance)

***UPDATE  11/01/2014***

Ok, i have found the problem... that was not about owl but about type of dumps. I resolved installing a VAD for faceted browsing and take the info about triple from local.host:8890/fct search engine.
Just a few modifies in the queries and all works good... :D 
Thanks all, expecially to mr.Taylor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result

```
http://it.dbpedia.org    86712483
```

in your original query means that there are 86712483 in the graph named http://it.dbpedia.org.  Your second query:

```sql
select ?museum, ?artwork where {
  ?museum a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Museum>. 
  ?museum <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/address> ?address.
  ?artwork <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/location> ?museum.
  filter contains(?address, "Firenze")
}
```

is a query over the *default graph*.  Some SPARQL endpoints make the default graph a union of all the other graphs, but this isn't universal, and it appears that it is not what Virtuoso does (or at least not by default).  You need to specify the actual named graph.  E.g., the following query will probably get you some results:

```sql
select ?museum, ?artwork where {
  graph <http://it.dbpedia.org> {
    ?museum a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Museum>. 
    ?museum <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/address> ?address.
    ?artwork <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/location> ?museum.
    filter contains(?address, "Firenze")
  }
}
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for the reply... i've tried this query but the result is empty... it's grammatically correct but nothing is in the input...i've modified the answer with new details...

Comment: @cataciandevil81 At this point, then, you probably just need to start incrementally debugging.  Try something like `select * from { graph <http://it.dbpedia.org> { ?s ?p ?o } }`.  What sort of results do you get?  Maybe the properties are in a different localized namespace?  Maybe there's no localized data that matches your query?  It's not reasonable for any of us to try to reproduce the exact setup (which, as you say, takes hours to set up), so it's really a question of debugging.  Your initial query shows that there are triples in the named graph;  the question now is what triples they are.

Comment: with this query i got a lot of "property items"... i paste 1 for example

Comment: http://it.dbpedia.org/property/goalTotali http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property

Comment: another one: http://it.dbpedia.org/property/featurig http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property    all are property.

Comment: The endpoint probably contains lots and lots of information, and it may wekll be that the ontological information about properties is the first thing that the endpoint returns. Note that the IRIs of those properties begin with `http://it.dbpedia.org/property/`, rather than `http://dbpedia.org/property/`.  Perhaps the issue in your query is something like that.  Maybe you need to use a `http://it.dbpedia.org/ontology/address` property, for instance.

Comment: mmm... still nothing... where can i see the ontology property that can i use?

Comment: You could try something like `?p a owl:ObjectProperty`.

Comment: Ok, i think it's the problem... it results: nothing... : meanwhile in the "official" dbpedia sparql: http://it.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=select+*+where+%7B%0D%0A%3Fp+a+owl%3AObjectProperty%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&debug=on